# perform function on criteria in SUMIF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am writing a `SUMIF` function on a range with a format such as:

```
   A       B
1  1.1     5
2  1.2     5
3  1.3     5
4  2.1     5
5  2.2     5
```

I want the `SUMIF` to group values together by their integer, i.e.:

```
   A    B
1  1    15
2  2    10
```

I can do this by creating a third column `C` and applying `INT(A)` so that:

```
   A       B    C
1  1.1     5    1
2  1.2     5    1
3  1.3     5    1
4  2.1     5    2
5  2.2     5    2
```

and (for 1)

```
=SUMIF(C:C, 1, B:B)
```

Is there a way to do this in one cell? i.e.

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5, "int(range) = 1", B1:B5)
```

I have also tried:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5, "1*", B1:B5)
```

and

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5, 1&"*", B1:B5)
```

But these also do not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INT($A$1:$A$5)=C1),$B$1:$B$5)
```

`INT($A$1:$A$5)=C1` produces an array of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s. The `--` operator converts that to an array of `0`s and `1`s. Then you multiply by the values in B.

[image]

Comment: I never knew about the numeric boolian operator before. This will be very handy; thank you

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Formula in cell F12 is:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$5;$A$1:$A$5;">="&E12;$A$1:$A$5;"<"&E12+1)
```

Drag down

Answer (score 2):

With ***Excel 365*** you can do it like-

```
 =LET(x,UNIQUE(INT(A1:A5)),y,SUMIFS(B1:B5,A1:A5,">="&x,A1:A5,"<"&x+1),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: If anyone interested to use `LAMBDA()` function can try `=LAMBDA(x,y,LET(p,INT(x),q,UNIQUE(p),r,SUMIFS(y,x,">="&q,x,"<"&q+1),CHOOSE({1,2},q,r)))(A1:A5,B1:B5)`